# Iterate through variables which are not present in an array in C

Tags: c++, c, macros, iteration

I have a list of variables (**not** present in an array) whose values have to be printed through **iteration**. These variables have same names except for the numbers which accompanies it at the end

Say following are the variable names;

```
int mem_size0;
int mem_size1;
int mem_size2;
...
...
int mem_sizen;
```

The total number of such variables is given by another variable `mem_size_entries`. These variables are generated for me by a different tool and I have to print the values of these variables with some sort of iteration. Is this possible to do using some **macros**?

Comment: Is `mem_size_entries` a compile-time constant?

Comment: Yes, it is a compile time constant which is generated by the tool as well.

Comment: Consult [Boost::Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor/), which has looping constructs.

Comment: Can you not get the other tool to put the values into an array?  That would be easier.

Comment: Nope, modifying the other tool is not under my control.

Comment: Your compiler might support the [`__COUNTER__`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(v=vs.80).aspx) prepreocessor macro. I'm not shure how you could make it stop iterating though...

Comment: As a customer, you may have some say in the issue of what the program produces.  A program producing an array of values into a list of vars like that is a pain.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Boost preprocessor is the best one that will help me I guess. Thanks for suggesting that.

Answer (score 2):

Use vim.

For example, you want to repeat the next line for all variables:

```
something mem_sizen0 something;
```

Just move over the begining of that line and press:

```
qa (start recording macro)
yy (copy line)
p (paste line in new line)
wwwhh (move to the 0)
ctrl+a (increase 0 by 1)
q (finish repeating macro)
30@a (repeat this 30 times, if this is the amount you need)
```

Answer (score 1):

If these variables are all declared in order, it seems likely (though not guaranteed) that they would occupy sequential locations in memory.  This may not work on all (or any!) compilers, but it's worth a try at least:

```
int mem_size0;
int mem_size1;
int mem_size2;
...
...
int mem_sizen;

const int *const start = &mem_size0;
const int *const end   = &mem_size0 + (mem_size_entries);

for (const int *p = start; p < end; p++)
{
    /* Do stuff with p... */
    printf("%i\n", *p);
}
```

Comment: To simplify, you could just have `#define mem_size(i) (*(&mem_size0 + i))` I can also confirm this works with GCC on Mac OSX Lion.

Comment: Sequential occupation of memory location is not guaranteed. So this is not a safe solution.

Comment: @AnandhKumar true, very true. However, I am not sure of a completely portable way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Wrapping the declarations in a struct would enforce that. Might not be possible though with generated code

Comment: Even if you wrap it in a struct, you might have padding issues :)

Comment: WHAT IS THE DEAL with people editing other people's answers?  Is that encouraged?  Discouraged?  It BUGS me.  Write your own answer, or write comments, or something.

Comment: @aldo: editing of answers is permitted, even encouraged, but must be done with integrity.  An edit to an answer should only make minor corrections such as to grammar or presentation; it should not change the meaning of the answer.  Similarly with questions.  Edits should respect the original question or answer.  See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can edit the generated code so that this:

```
int mem_size0;
int mem_size1;
int mem_size2;
...
...
int mem_sizen;
```

becomes:

```
union {
struct {
int mem_size0;
int mem_size1;
int mem_size2;
...
...
int mem_sizen;
} s;
int mem_array[mem_size_entries];
} u;
```

Now you can iterate over the elements of `u.mem_array`.

This can be done fairly simply with a shell script (or `perl` script); the tricky part is recognizing when you've reached `mem_sizen` or the line after it.  This seems to work for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my($seen, $done) = (0, 0);
while (<>)
{
    if (/mem_size0/)
    {
        print "struct { union {\n";
        $seen = 1;
    }
    if ($seen && !$done && !/mem_size/)
    {
        print "} s; int mem_array[mem_size_entries]; } u;\n";
        $done = 1;
    }
    print $_;
}
```

Given input:

```
int mem_size0;
int mem_size1;
int mem_size2;
int mem_sizen;
```

with a blank line (or any other line not containing `mem_size`) after those declarations.

The script generates the output:

```
struct { union {
int mem_size0;
int mem_size1;
int mem_size2;
int mem_sizen;
} s; int mem_array[mem_size_entries]; } u;
```

You can lay that out more prettily without much difficulty.  You can then iterate over the array in `u`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mem_size_entries; i++)
    printf("%d: %d\n", i, u.mem_array[i]);
```

The downside of this is that the initializers are not shown in the original code; however, with Perl, you could readily arrange to recognize how many there are and find the initializations and edit them to fit this scheme.  Basically, this is treating the generated output of the program as a source code in a 'higher level language' and then 'compiling' it into C code that you can compile.